# Regex Select & Replace to Clean Up US phone numbers

Tags: regex, mariadb

We pull in a list of phone numbers as part of a datafeed. They are all for North America based companies. I would like to remove any leading "1" or "+1" and any trailing information like "x100", " EXT400", etc. They are stored in MariaDB so I would like to do

```
UPDATE `CompanyPhone` SET `number`= REGEXP_SUBSTR(`number`,pattern)
```

to remove the unwanted stuff, I just need the REGEX to select the correct part of the phone number.

```
"1 (555) 555-5555 x100" -> "(555) 555-5555"
"+15555555555 EXT400" -> "5555555555"
" 555-555-5555" -> "555-555-5555" (remove leading space)
```

Basically, I need just the first 10 digits, ignoring the first digit if it is a 1, and the formatting currently in the first 10 digits ("()" or " " or "-") if it is possible to keep it.

If everything could be reformatted to (555) 555-5555 that would be a bonus but is not required. I could do this a 2nd query if needed.

Comment: Surely there are better ways than using regex for this. A simple procedure that strips all characters in a string that is not a digit would work just fine. But as your question is right now, it's too broad and probably won't get much help if you don't make an attempt first, as SO is not a code-writing service, but a service that helps fix and correct existing code.

Comment: I need a database query as that is the only access I have to the data right now, and with how this data is used I don't have control on the outputs so I would prefer to not drop formatting as it makes the numbers much harder to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/regexp_replace/) for this. Assuming you are using MariaDB 10.0.5 or later, you can use `PCRE` regular expressions. For your sample expressions, this regexp will give you the desired results ([demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pT4tM5/61)). It looks for 3 groups of numbers (3 digits, 3 digits and then 4 digits) possibly preceded by a 1, and with other non-digit characters (e.g. `+`, `-`) around them.

```
^(?:\D*)1?(?:\D*)(\d{3})(?:\D*)(\d{3})(?:\D*)(\d{4}).*$
```

So your `UPDATE` statement will become

```
UPDATE `CompanyPhone` SET `number`= REGEXP_REPLACE(`number`, '^(?:\\D*)1?(?:\\D*)(\\d{3})(?:\\D*)(\\d{3})(?:\\D*)(\\d{4}).*$', '(\\1) \\2-\\3')
```